# Ajax auto complete - not to fire a call when the input is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

i have an element which has a list of some names and on top of it i have a text box. when a user starts typing, an ajax call is fired and names with the matching keywords are fetched. I need to stop any call if there is only a white space but should the text box be empty without any spaces, the list should be populated with all names.

The HTML is :

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="startTSearch(); return false" class="t_search_placeholder" id="t_Search" placeholder="Search here" />
```

JS is like so:

```
function startTSearch(){
var list = $('.teachersList');
var q = document.getElementById('t_Search').value;
q = q.trim();
if(q == ""){}else{
list.html("");
$('.t_loader_msg').css('display','block');
$('.t_loader_msg').css('font-weight','bold');
document.getElementById('load_MSG').innerHTML = "RETRIEVING SUGGESTIONS...";


var postData = {flag:1,q:q};
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 dataType: 'json',
 url: 'global.php',
 data: postData,
 beforeSend:function(){

},
success:function(data){

if(data.errorList == ""){
    if(data.hasResult == 0){    
  document.getElementById('load_MSG').innerHTML = "NO RESULTS FOUND.";
        } else if(data.hasResult == 1){
    document.getElementById('load_MSG').style.display = "none";
    list.hide().html(data.teacherList).slideDown(300); 
       }    
   }
 },
 error:function(){

    }

});
    }
}
```

The above code doesnt fire a call when the user presses space but if the user has searched for some initial, lets say, A, then it searches all names with A but when user presses backspaces to get the text box empty it searches nothing which i understand but i want the call to be made to fetch all names if backspaces are pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the length of input first and later check length after remove the trailing and leading whitespaces.If they are different and the latter empty,do not fire AJAX request.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more pls?

Comment: Suppose the input is "    ".Now the length is 4.After you remove the traling and leading whitespaces the string now becomes ""(empty) in which case you dont need to fire a call.(If the input is empty intially then you need to make an AJAX call)